# Assigning an array of TextViews to XML

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml

I have an array of TextViews like so:

```
 TextView arrayTxtAssignedMiners[] = new TextView[1];
```

and two TextViews in my XML

```
android:id="@+id/txtAssignedMiners0"
android:id="@+id/txtAssignedMiners1"
```

I then have tried to assign the xml components to my array of TextViews inside the onCreate method

```
arrayTxtAssignedMiners[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAssignedMiners0);
arrayTxtAssignedMiners[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAssignedMiners1);
```

The application crashes when I try to assign XML to slots in the array.

How do i properly approach this? Thanks!

Comment: your array size is one, but you are trying to save two elements to the array. change into this `TextView arrayTxtAssignedMiners[] = new TextView[2];`

Answer (score 0):

Change `arrayTxtAssignedMiners` lenght to 2.
    `TextView arrayTxtAssignedMiners[] = new TextView[2];`